# Android: OpenStreetMap - Public Transport Layer

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I am quite new to this topic, so maybe i have the wrong thinking. But please help me ;)
The only think i want to see is a normal map of my location with the public transport stops and lines next to me. 
But i only get a black screen with the public transport data.

I thought the public transport tile has the mapnik tile as background.

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapactivity);
    final MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    mapView.getController().setZoom(16);
    mapView.setUseDataConnection(true);

    ResourceProxy resourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());

   // mapView.getTileProvider().setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
   // mapView.getTileProvider().setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
       mapView.getTileProvider().setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.PUBLIC_TRANSPORT);

    myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(this, mapView);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();

    myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                mapView.getController().animateTo(myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
            }
            catch (Exception e){}
        }
    });

}
```

If i change from the public transport tile to the mapnik or the mapquestosm tile, the app shows me a correct map. But how can i put the public transport data into it if not as a second tile?

Comment: You didn't mention the mapping framework. Consider the PT tile provider to be broken or that you will need to get an API key to accept the usage policy?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I don't think that i need a API key - the Bus stops and lines are visible. It just seems like to standard layer is missing. Can you give me an example for a mapping framework? My problem is that i can't find any usable information to that topic - but propably i am just searching the wrong way...

Comment: Which Android framework/API/widget are you using to display the background map and the layer on top?